# Is it possible to login with a different user per workspace?

Tags: linux

In an Kali linux "USB persistence" installation, is it possible to login with a different  user per workspace from the menu login ?
Whenever I login with a new user in a new workspace, all the workspaces are then logged-in as that new user.
I need simultaneously, Workspace 1 as root, Workspace 2 as User1, Workspace 3 as User2 and so on. Possible?

Comment: I don't think it'd be possible to have a different user per workspace but as an alternative you could use the alternative shells?

If you use ctrl+alt+[num] you can switch and login as someone else. If you then startx from there you could switch between different users' workspaces.

(I've not tried this but it would be a possibility to look into)